# Twilio how to disconnect the call when an agent transferred the call to another agent

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

E.g.->If agent A makes a call to a user and now agent A transfers the call the agent B now how can i disconnect agent A from the call and let user and B still on the call.

1.When I make the call I use this TwiML.

```
<Response>
        <Dial  callerId="id">
            <Number  statusCallback="statusCallbackurl" statusCallbackMethod="POST">ag1_num</Number>
        </Dial>
        <Redirect>music_url</Redirect> 
    </Response>
```

2.I am transferring the call by using update method and dialing the other agent by using this code-

```
function transfer_call($Sid,&ag2_num){
    $childCalls = $this->client->calls->read(array("ParentCallSid" => $Sid));
    $childSid = $childCalls[0]->sid;
    $rr = array(
        "url" => "tr_url".$ag2_num,
        "method" => "POST"

    );
    $call = $this->client->calls($childSid)->update($rr);
    return $call->to;

}
```

and on the tr_url I used TwiML-

```
<Response>
  <Dial>ag2_num</Dial>
  <Redirect>disconnectedcallurl-usingemptyqueue(todisconnectthefirstagent)</Redirect>
</Response>
```

and to disconnect the call I called this method and pass the callsid-

```
function disconnect_call($callsid){
        $rr = array("status" => "completed");

        $call = $this->client->calls($callsid)->update($rr);
        echo $call->direction;
    }
```

I use the call sid to disconnect the agent from the call and it disconnect the whole call.

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code please?

Comment: Okay sure I will add in my question.

Comment: When you redirect the other end of the call away, the 1st agent who was dialled should just hang up. Is that not happening?

Comment: yes you r right .//*that is what I want(the 1st agent who was dialled should just hang up), but what is happening is it disconnect the whole call (every on the call get disconnected).*//

Comment: Are there any errors in your [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger)?

Comment: no there are not errors on debugger.

Comment: did you figure out anything?

Comment: What Sid are you using in the disconnect call method? And when do you call that?

Comment: I m using the callsid to disconnect the first agent(ag1_num) from the call and I m using it right after my transfer_call method=>   `function transfer_call($Sid,&ag2_num){
    $childCalls = $this->client->calls->read(array("ParentCallSid" => $Sid));
    $childSid = $childCalls[0]->sid;
    $rr = array(
        "url" => "tr_url".$ag2_num,
        "method" => "POST"

    );
    $call = $this->client->calls($childSid)->update($rr);
    
$this->disconnect_call($childSid );
}`.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In the comments you say you are using the `disconnect_call` method straight after the transfer and you are using the same sid for both. This means that you transfer the call, which hangs up from the first agent, but then you instantly hang up the transferred call too, so it never calls the second agent.

You shouldn't need to disconnect the first agent, transferring the call away from them will do that. Remove your call to `disconnect_child` and try again.

Comment: I tried that too but it does not disconnect the agent1 from the call.

Comment: What happens to the first agent then? Where do they go? What do they hear?

Comment: It start listing the music from the `<Redirect>music_url</Redirect> ` that is used when the agent1 make the call for the first time.

Comment: Ah, ok, you can remove that `<Redirect>` then, the agent doesn't need music if they are going the the call.

Comment: Actually I used that To put user on Hold.If  I removed that then the hold functionality won't work

Comment: Ok, then use the parent SID in the call to disconnect. The parent call is the one that initiated the call and in this case the call originated from the agent.